# QSqlQuery does not work

Tags: database, qt

I try to add to my database a row but it does not work.
My database is host by alwaysdata, I use Qt Creator to develop my program (which print no error) and MySql for viewing the database

via MySql Query Browser I entered :

```
INSERT INTO `mmr` VALUES (NULL,'musictest','albumtest','timetest','datetest');
```

it works
but in my program that code does not work :

```
void MainWindow::b_clicked(){
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName("mysql1.alwaysdata.com");
    db.setDatabaseName("mymusicrecognition_mmr");
    db.setUserName("xxx");
    db.setPassword("yyyy");
    if(!db.open())
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this,"Message","Not connected...");
    }
    else{

        QSqlQuery query;
        query.exec(QString("INSERT INTO `mmr` VALUES (NULL,'%1','%2','%3','%4')")
        .arg("musictest").arg("albumtest").arg("timetest").arg("datetest"));
        QMessageBox::information(this,"Message","Connected !!!");
    }
}
```

I have the message box "Connected !!!"

This must be a beginner mistake

Comment: can you check the return value of QSqlQuery::exec? You can do something like `bool success = query.exec(...); if ( ! success ) qDebug() << query.lastError();` to get the message of a possible error during the execution

Comment: QSqlError("1", "Unable to execute statement", "no such table: mmr")

Comment: "QSQLITE" driver... and then using some remote hostname?. And you haven't even bothered to check what the lastError() even was.

Comment: haha, it's because I don't know about those things man ^^ You don't even consider that I can be a beginner !!

Comment: It's fine to be a newbie and ask questions, but please don't make blanket statements like "QSqlQuery does not work" just because you haven't yet figured out how to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of construction QString from args try prepared QSqlQuery and binding the values.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values

QString doesnt know anything about sql escaping. You use Sqlite driver so instead of connecting to your hostname qt tried sqlite file

Comment: ok i'm all wrong, I just discovered what is sqlite and I want to use MySql with database hosted on alwaysdata
thank u for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have here it looks like you're not passing the database to QSqlQuery.

Instead of

```
QSqlQuery query;
```

try this

```
QSqlQuery query(db);
```

I'd also recommend that you take this a step further by creating a separate variable for your sql statement, and then passing that in as an argument along with the database.  Like the following:

```
QString insertSql = QString("INSERT INTO `mmr` VALUES (NULL,'%1','%2','%3','%4')")
        .arg("musictest").arg("albumtest").arg("timetest").arg("datetest");
QSqlQuery query(insertSql, db);
```

This will also allow you to verify that you have a properly constructed sql statement in the debugger before you try to run it.  
After this, you can call exec() and store the result in a bool (as others on here have mentioned).

```
bool checkSuccess = query.exec();
```

Your code above will run without failing.  exec() will just return false since it didn't have anything to run the sql statement against.